# How can I make cmd+c send ctrl+c in VS Code's terminal, in macOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like for `cmd+c` to have the same effect as pressing `ctrl+c` in the VS Code terminal in macOS (so that it terminates the current process and drops me back into a new command prompt).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a keybinding for <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> that triggers the `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` command:

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u0003" },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

When the above keybinding is added to your keybindings.json file (<kbd>F1</kbd>, "keybindings") <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will send the character `\u0003` which is `^C` (ETX), but only when you have focused the terminal.

You can find more documentation on this command in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That worked. It made such a positive impact on my work flow: no more pinky gymnastics.

Comment: How about other ctrl+ strokes? Do I have to map all of them?

Comment: You would have to map all of them if you wanted to do that, ctrl+key has special meaning for terminal emulators and making it so that cmd does that too. You can see this file for how the keyboard events are serialized https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/30161c3b5a0428f6e7c706cf2dc775506fdac74a/src/common/input/Keyboard.ts

Comment: For those searching to remap "cmd+a" (bol) and "cmd+e" (eol), the escape codes are ``\u0001`` and ``\u0005`` respectively.